# How to deal with Dom MisMatch - React Hydration failure because of extensions injecting elements inside HEAD tag?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-dom, serverside-javascript

I was trying to get a sense of how React SSR works . Now I have this code https://github.com/kritidipto-1234/ssr-without-next

So basically I am just using **renderToString** to generate my HTML on server and then using React **hydrateRoot** on client bundle.  I am generating whole HTML page and within that there is obviously the HEAD tag. Now I have an extension that injects some elements into HEAD tag. This causes React to freak out and give Hydration errors.
When I turn off that extension all works perfectly fine as HEAD isnt modified.

**App.jsx**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <html>  //is this not the correct way to Generate HTML page?
      <head>
        <title>My server side app!</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>Hello world!</div>
        <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**Server.js**

```
expressApp.use(express.static("dist/client"));

expressApp.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);
  res.send(html);
});

expressApp.listen(port, () => { console.log(`App listening!`); });
```

**Index.js(Client bundle)-->bundle.js**

```
import { hydrateRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";

hydrateRoot(document, <App />);
```

[image: hydration error]